# Facebook messenger media template send problem

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I can not send video by messenger. Standard templates and messages send successfully, but video can't. How correct send video template?

[image]

[image]

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
      "recipient":{
        "id":"...665"
      },
      "message":{
        "attachment": {
          "type": "template",
          "payload": {
             "template_type": "media",
             "elements": [
                {
                   "media_type": "video",
                   "url": "https://www.facebook.com/100559414942740/videos/925282991363243"
                }
             ]
          }
        }    
      }
    }' "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me/messages?access_token=..KUZCIBNSv"
```

Error:

> {"error":{"message":"(#100) Invalid message data","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2534015,"fbtrace_id":"AfizMhFPOd7EiOvrHac5Q9_"}}